# C# Creating String sequence with specific LAST VALUE

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a sequence of numbers in string format, once I reach "99999" I want to continue the sequence using leading letters and will start base on my last value in database.

Example Sequence:

```
"00000" -> "00100" -> "99999" -> "A0001" -> "A9999" -> "B0001" -> "Z9999" -> "AA001" -> "ZZZZZ"
```

I have database and has row that has 00001 to 99995 values
and need to increment base on last number which is `99995`.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from Table ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1"
string lastvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
int quantity = 10;
total = lastvalue + quantity;

for (i = lastvalue; i < total; i++)
{

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES ('"+i+"')";
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();

}
```

Expected Output

```
99996
99997
99998
99999
A0000
A0001
A0002
A0003
A0004
A0005
```

Comment: What is your [minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'll suggest you save first digit in hex.

Comment: i already edit it i hope you understand

Comment: This is a terrible idea and will take more storage space than numeric values and even more time to process (parsing > incrementing > converting back to string). Why don't you store regular numeric values and then format them when you read from the database to display to the user?

Comment: because it will print as serial. and need to be scan like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850629/12744547 found this answer but without specific start and end. it just genereate from start until the end base on the length.

Answer (score 0):

The lower 4 digits you want in the decimal system ?
That would be (number % 10000)

The upper part you want in an Base 36 system. (10 digits + 26 characters)

Any given integer in `number`,also beyond 9999,  you can convert this this:

```
public string FormatNumber(long number)
{  
  string result = (number % 10000).ToString();
  number /= 10000;
  while(number > 0)
  {
    int digit = number % 36;
    if (digit < 10)
       result = digit.ToString() + result;
    else
       result = (char)('A' + digit - 10) + result;
   number /=36
  }
  return result;
}
```